# History.js recovering state with ie6/ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, history.js

I've been using History.js successfully with my HTML5 browsers and IE8/9, but even though I'm using the html4+html5 jQuery version, it's not working in ie6/ie7.

With the following code, I expect the state.data to be restored when I click on an ordinary link from the main page, then hit the back button to get back to the main page.

The main page contains the following code, which is invoked by submitting a form:

```
if (window.History && window.History.enabled) {
  var vars = {};
  var tables = {};
  vars['something'] = 'value';
  History.replaceState({vars: vars, tables: tables}, null, window.location.href.match(/^([^#]*)/)[1]);
}
```

This page has an onload function which looks like this:

```
var state = History.getState();
var data = state.data;

    if (data.vars) {
          alert('success!');
    }
```

It doesn't display success under IE6/IE7, though it works just fine on any of the other browsers I've tried.

Do you see anything obviously missing, or have an idea on how to proceed?  I tried debugging the non-minified version of history.html4.js and history.js, but I'm not understanding the subtlety of interactions.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you will never get History.js to work with a browser that doesn't support the `onHashChange` event, because History.js uses `pushState` (only in html5) for compatibility browsers, and "#hash" for html4 browsers that supports this event. Even ie9 uses hash instead ofpushState. But, again, neither ie6 nor ie7 support the hash event.

Comment: This isn't exactly true. For browsers that don't support the hash event and pushState, a setInterval and iframe are used to emulate the hashchange event and the history handling. https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/blob/master/scripts/uncompressed/history.html4.js#L248